# Applying a simple function to CSV and save multiple csv files

Tags: python, csv, numpy, export-to-csv

I am trying to replicate the data by multiplying every value with a range of values and save the results as CSV.

I have created a function "Replicate_Data" which takes the input numpy array and multiply with a random value between a range. What is the best way to create a 100 files and save as P3D1 , P4D1 and so on.

```
def Replicate_Data(data: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    Rep_factor= random.uniform(-3,7)
    data1 = data * Rep_factor
    return data1

P2D1 = Replicate_Data(P1D1)
np.savetxt("P2D1.csv", P2D1, delimiter="," , dtype = complex)
```

Comment: It would help, you and us, if made a clear(er) distinction between `csv`, the file, and the structure (array or list) that you start with.  We don't apply functions to the text in the csv file.  Start with a small `ndarray`, and make sure the function returns the correct one.  Leave the csv load and save till later.

Comment: In your function, you assign to `data1` but don't save or collect that between loops.  Then you return the original `data`.  Also you don't make use of the `x` iteration variable.

Comment: I still don't see what your for loop does, except waste time

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj The input as a csv file containing 06 rows and 200 columns of complex type. The data is readed as P1D1 = genfromtxt('path', delimiter=',', dtype = 'complex') .

Comment: @hpaulj Yes you are right. I have removed the loop and got the same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example you can use as reference.

I generate toy data named `toy`, then I make `n` random values using `np.random.uniform` and call it `randos`, then I multiply these two objects to form `out` using numpy broadcasting. You could also do this multiplication in a loop (the same one you save in, in fact): depending on the size of your input array it could be very memory intensive as I've written it. A more complete answer probably depends on the shape of your input data.

```
import numpy as np
toy = np.random.random(size=(2,2)) # a toy input array
n = 100 # number of random values
randos = np.random.uniform(-3,7,size=n) # generate 100 uniform randoms
# now multiply all elements in toy by the randoms in randos
out = toy[None,...]*randos[...,None,None] # this depends on the shape.
# this will work only if toy has two dimensions. Otherwise requires modification
# it will take a lot of memory... 100*toy.nbytes worth

# now save in the loop.. 
for i,o in enumerate(out):
    name = 'P{}D1'.format(str(i+1))
    np.savetxt(name,o,delimiter=",")


# a second way without the broadcasting (slow, better on memory)
# more like 2*toy.nbytes
#for i,r in enumerate(randos):
#    name = 'P{}D1'.format(str(i+1))
#    np.savetxt(name,r*toy,delimiter=",")
```

Comment: Thanks @kevinkayaks. The input as a csv file containing 06 rows and 200 columns of complex type. The data is readed as P1D1 = genfromtxt('path', delimiter=',', dtype = 'complex'). I have tried this example and it worked however it is creating braces "()" around each value in output csv.

Comment: probably you need to clean up `o` before you save it. Check out `o.shape` and see if it has an extra empty axis. If so, you can strip it before saving. For example if `o.shape` returned `(1,1,200') you would save `o[:,0,:]` in each iteration of the loop -- kills the extra axis. Anyway, just guessing. good luck